# JSONP call mathod on API working on local but not on deploy

Tags: angular, typescript, xmlhttprequest, jsonp, angular-httpclient

I'm using [TheMovieDB Api](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3) which uses [JSON method](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/json-and-jsonp)

In my service I use JSONP module.

```
getList(input) {
  const url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie/?api_key=b6dba21fefcead0c857d43&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK&query=' + input;
  return this.jsonp.request(url, { method: 'Get' });
}
```

In component I subscribe to it and it's working

```
this.sharedService.getList(message)
.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data['_body'])
  this.dataResult = <FilmCard[]>data['_body']['results'];
});
```

In local data is retrieved from API server. but when I deploy it in github pages I get this error

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://githamza.github.io/ngxs-app-example/home' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=b6dba21fefcdf58eb57d43&callback=__ng_jsonp__.__req2.finished&query=cal'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

However in my url I'm using `https` and not `http`.

Comment: Paste `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie/` into your browser address bar and notice what happens: It redirects to the corresponding non-https URL. So there’s actually no usable https URL for that API endpoint, which means you can’t use it securely, which means browsers won’t let you make requests to successfully from a document/web-application served at a secure (https) origin.

Comment: my bad .. after nights of dev.. no online demo :/